# What is the right way to call a Task from MainPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, task

If await can be used only by async methods, how can I call a task from MainPage()?

My code sample:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label.Text=await Task.Run(TaskTest); //this doesn't work
}

private async Task<string> TaskTest()
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
               return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.example.com/return.php");
//also tried w/ no success:
//return client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.example.com/return.php").Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't. Constructors are not meant for creating asynchronous flows. You may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283681/the-async-method-is-not-await/51284217#51284217)

Comment: label.Text = await Task.Run is very confusing. UI runs on a separate thread. You may want to assign a value to await task and then assign it to label.Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `async void` fire-and-forget methods.

Event handlers however are the only exception to that rule.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

In this case, since you want to await the task then create and event and handler that would facilitate the desired behavior

```
public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Downloading += OnDownloading; //subscribe to event
    Downloading(this, EventArgs.Empty); //raise event to be handled
}

private event EventHandler Downloading = delegate { };

private async void OnDownloading(object sender, EventArgs args) {
     //Downloading -= OnDownloading; //unsubscribe (optional)
    label.Text = await TaskTest(); //this works
}

private async Task<string> TaskTest() {
    try {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
           return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.example.com/return.php");
        }
    } catch (Exception) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the `Main()` method asynchronous and thus, you can use the `await` keyword in the body of the `Main()` function.

A simple workaround that you can implement by editing your current code is making your function `TaskTest()` return `void` so you don't have to await it's call.

**Example:**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TaskTest();
}
private async void TaskTest()
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
           label.Text = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.example.com/return.php");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

In case you have to wait for the return value of an asynchronous call without using `await`, you could go ahead and use a while to check whether the `Task` has completed or not.

```
Task<string> accessTokenTask = Task.Run<string>(() => MethodToGetToken());
// wait until operation is done.
while(!accessTokenTask.IsCompleted)
{
    accessTokenTask.Wait():
}
// once the task completes, the runtime will step out of the while loop
// and you can access your Token in the Result

string token = accessTokenTask.Result;
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, @machariadev ! But if I wanted to wait? For exemple, if the returned string was actually a login token and I had to wait its response to show some data or no. Can you give me this assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't call your `Task` from `MainPage`. I started with the Visual Studio blank page and tried to do the same thing. I found an answer suggested to use `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(NewPage);`, and then call the task there `Task.Run(async () => { await method(); }).Wait();`. It worked, but [not the best way to do it](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89535/pushmodalasnyc-await-does-not-wait-how-to-fix).

This [article on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1274851/Xamarin-Forms-Validations-Made-Simple) is great to help beginners to add `MVVM` to the blank page project. You just need to bind the `ViewModel` to the `MainPage`, and then call your `Task` from the `ViewModel` instead.

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel(this);
}
```